# Copy Files to Directory and Overwrite if theres any Collisions

Tags: windows, installation, nsis

I am attempting to move files from directory A to directory B. When I move the files into directory B, if there are any collisions then I want the files from A to overwrite the collisions in B.

Will my following code do this?

```
SetOverwrite ifnewer 
CopyFiles \SILENT "Directories/Directory_A/" "Directories/Directory_B"
```

*Note: I am aware of the function [MoveFileFolder](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/MoveFileFolder) but I am experiencing buggy behaviour where the files are not being moved when the function is called.*

Comment: Did you tried to put some tracing info into the `MoveFile` / `MoveFolder` code (with either `DetailPrint` or `${debug}` to see where is the unexpected behavior? Maybe that you have a file time  or access issue (security settings)?

Answer (score 0):

according to the docs, [SetOverwrite](https://github.com/NSIS-Handbook/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/SetOverwrite.md) only works with the [File](https://github.com/NSIS-Handbook/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/File.md) command. if your overwriting criteria is based on the file date, you might want to have a look at [GetTime](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/GetTime), if it's file existence use [IfFileExists](https://github.com/NSIS-Handbook/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/IfFileExists.md)